# ZF2 how to wrap content in form fieldset?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have form with fieldsets:

```
$formConfig = array(
    'fieldsets' => array(
        ...
    );
);

$factory = new Zend\Form\Factory();
$form = $factory->createForm($formConfig); 
echo $this->form($form);
```

It renders something like this:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fieldset label</legend>
        <label><span>Elem 1</span><input type="text" name="f1[el1]" /></label>
        <label><span>Elem 2</span><input type="text" name="f1[el2]" /></label>
        <label><span>Elem 3</span><input type="text" name="f1[el3]" /></label>
    </fielset>
</form>
```

The problem is that I need to wrap content after legend:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fieldset label</legend>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label><span>Elem 1</span><input type="text" name="f1[el1]" /></label>
            <label><span>Elem 2</span><input type="text" name="f1[el2]" /></label>
            <label><span>Elem 3</span><input type="text" name="f1[el3]" /></label>
        <div>
    </fielset>
</form>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once more you need to understand that a `Zend\Form\Fieldset` does not equal a HTML `<fieldset>`! A `Zend\Form\Fieldset` merely is a collection of `Zend\Form\Element` that usually represent one entity and you could provide several entities with data from one Form.

Now when it comes to rendering the form, the first thing you should learn about are the several [`Zend\Form\View\Helper`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Form/View/Helper)-Classes. You are using the `form()` view-helper, which automatically translates all `Zend\Form\Element` using `formRow()` and all `Zend\Form\Fieldset` using `formCollection()`. But you don't want to do that!

When wanting your preferred output, you will be needed to render the form yourself. Something like this could be your view-template:

```
<?=$this->form()->openTag($form);?>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?=$this->formRow($form->get('f1')->get('el1'));?>
            <?=$this->formRow($form->get('f1')->get('el2'));?>
            <?=$this->formRow($form->get('f1')->get('el3'));?>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
<?=$this->form()->closeTag();?>
```

Now, this already has a little comfort within it, as you'd be using `formRow()`. You could also split up each form-row and go the very detailled way like:

```
<label>
    <span><?=$this->formLabel($form->get('f1')->get('el1'));?></span>
    <?=$this->formInput($form->get('f1')->get('el1'));=>
    <?=$this->formElementErrors($form->get('f1')->get('el1'));?>
</label>
```

Even there, `formInput()` still is a magic that derives into things like `formText()`, `formSelect()`, `formTextarea()`, etc.., etc...

Comment: +1 for the Fieldset clarification. What a horrid naming choice on part of the ZF2 community. Why not go with FieldCollection or something less ambiguous and confusing?