# How to add a "new line" after a ZF2 form element?

Tags: php, css, zend-framework2

Using ZF2 I am trying to place `<br>` or a similar element between my form elements.  ZF1 had something like "Decorators" which are no longer in ZF2 to my knowledge.  However, ZF2 does not have something `$form->addBr()` element, and that is what I need.

Here is how I render a form in my View:

```
<?php echo $this->form($this->form);?>
```

Here is how I prepare my `$form` in my controller

```
    // Set up checkbox
    $checkbox = new Element\Checkbox('checkbox');
    $checkbox->setChecked(true);

    //Set up text
    $text = new Element\Text('text');
    $text->setLabel("Hi");
    $text->setValue(333);

    // Assemble Fielset
    $fieldset = new Fieldset("FS");
    $fieldset->setLabel("Label");

    $fieldset->add($checkbox);

    //NOTE:  I need a "NEW LINE" Here
    $fieldset->ADD_NEW_LINE();// no such method 


    $fieldset->add($text);

    // Assemble Form
    $form = new Form();
    $form->add($fieldset);
```

**Current Issue:**

Form elements render out on a single line when I want them to be on a new line each.

**Question**

When I want to ZF2 just render the entire form in one go, like I try to do here (preferably without having code in view that renders out the form line by line), how can I make it so that I can place new form elements on new lines?

I am open to any solutions -- whether it be programmatic ZF2 solutions or CSS solutions (if possible) or other solutions I can't think of yet.  I just want the form to render out with elements being shown on new lines instead of showing up on a single line.

**ZF2 Renders HTML like so:**

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  <label><span>Check</span>
    <input name="name[checkbox]" value="0" type="hidden">
    <input name="name[checkbox]" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
  </label>

  <label><span>Value</span>
    <input name="name[text]" value="123" type="text">
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: sigh ... thinking about it maybe I should just do the "row by row" approach in view, kind of like here http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.view.helper.form-row.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this happen -- essentially copied [ZF2's own mechanisms](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/release-2.7.0/src/View/Helper/Form.php#L66) and got some help from this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15827116/2883328

I removed `FieldSet` that was only messing me up, and then used a loop to cycle through the Form elements, amending `<br/>` where I wanted it - after each element.  So much for that.

```
<?php
/**
 * inside view template
 *
 * @var $this \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer
 * @var $form \Zend\Form\Form
 */
$form = $this->form;
?>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    <?php
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
    foreach ($form as $element)
        $formContent .= $this->formrow($element) . "<br/>"; //note the "BR"

    echo $formContent;
    echo $this->form()->closeTag();

    ?>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either do this with CSS or override the `formRow()` helper (which the `form()` helper uses) to output the markup you want.

I created a simple module that overrides the form row helper to output divs (with appropriate classes for styling): https://packagist.org/packages/tfountain/tf-form - feel free to either use this or copy the approach and customise to suit your needs. Mine will give you markup like this:

```
<div id="some_element" class="form-row form-row-text">
    <label><span>Value</span>
        <input name="name[text]" value="123" type="text">
    </label>
</div>
```

If you want to roll your own similar solution, this is the helper code: https://github.com/tfountain/tf-form/blob/master/src/TfForm/Form/View/Helper/FormRow.php